# How to add multiple panel nodes to a panel page

Tags: views, panels, nodes

What I need to achieve is essentially a panel page of panel nodes.

I have contact information for various divisions of a company. Then I used panel node to override the layout of these nodes. Now I need to maintain that layout and add them to a panel page or view.

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little playing around with views I solved it... the solution to my problem can be done in 2 ways.

The first way is to use views to simply create the list of nodes and then using some css, manipulate the containers and fields to position them the way you would like.

The second way is, if you have panels and views installed, you can select 'Panel fields' as the format to show the content on screen. This obviously has a whole lot of settings you can set to customize your layout.

[image]

After much frustration and lost time, the second way really solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Panel nodes was once totally awesome.

They could only do so much though, largely because of limitations in the underlying nodes.

With D7, Panelizer can what panel nodes could, but on any entity. I would strongly recommend you switch to panelize. Not only will you be able to easily use any regular method to list, but panel nodes have effectively been abandoned for years now.

Comment: I have never used Panelizer but I will definitely give it a try and hope it solves my problem. Thanks.

Comment: @Terence Wrote the above from my phone, so it may be a bit short. Let me know if there's anything I should expand with, but generally, Panelizer is the way forward. A long time ago there was an upgrade path from PN to Panelizer as well. Not sure if it ever got completed.